# How to find given file is a symbolic (soft) link or hard link

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, symlink

With c code, I want to know the given file (like test.c) is a symbolic link or not. I tried with stat() function. 
I am checking the

```
nlink_t   st_nlink;   /* number of hard links */
```

member of stat structure.

```
struct stat stbuf;
stat("test.c", &stbuf)
```

`stbuf.st_nlink` is giving one in case of hard link as well as in softlink.

Is that i am doing right. Or is there any other way to check the given file is a soft link or hard link.

Comment: See here for the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635923/how-do-you-determine-using-stat-whether-a-file-is-a-symbolic-link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you need to use [`lstat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat) to be able to detect if a file is a soft link.

Also make sure that you understand that typically, there are not three different types of files: files, hard links to files, and soft links to files. Instead, there are only two: hard links to files and soft links. What you might think of as "the file" is in fact a hard link too, it's just typically the single link.

Comment: I am using this code
struct stat stbuf;
stat("softlink_uname.c", &stbuf))
if (S_IFLNK == stbuf.st_mode & S_IFMT)
   printf("this is a soft link\n");
else if (S_IFREG == stbuf.st_mode & S_IFMT)
  printf("this is not a link\n");
But nothing is printing, Is i am did somthing wrong?

Comment: @Abhiteshkhatri Yes, you're using the wrong function, like I said you must use `lstat()`, **not** `stat()`, do detect soft links.

Comment: thanks, sorry it is typing mistake , now i am using lstat but nothing is printing.

Comment: thnx , I got the error..Now it is working.