# How to find all the hard and symbolic links to a file/folder (Windows and UNIX)?

Tags: c++, winapi, filesystems, symlink, hardlink

How to find all the hard and symbolic links to a file/folder in Windows (using standard OS functions)?

What is opposed to UNIX?

Answer (score 2):

From this nice tutorial for linux:

https://jackal.livejournal.com/2164247.html

Get the inode number:

```
ls -i FILENAME
```

Find file by inode number:

```
find / -inum INODE-NUM-FROM-ABOVE
```

Optionally restrict `find` to speed up the search.

Example:

```
> ls -i myfile.csv 
74714625 myfile.csv

> find ~/myfolder/ -inum 74714625
/home/me/myfolder/myfile.csv
/home/me/myfolder/another/path/another_filename_with_same_inode.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

**Symlinks:**

You´ll have to search all files on all hard disks etc.etc. and check each of them individually. Otherwise it´s not possible to get a list of symlinks for a specific file.

For Linux, [How do you determine using stat() whether a file is a symbolic link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635923/how-do-you-determine-using-stat-whether-a-file-is-a-symbolic-link) may help.

For Windows ... well, Reparse points are not explainable in one line.
It´s not trivial to check if a file is a symlink from C++.

**Hard links:**

Linux: Again (usually) not possible without searching all files and checking the inode number.

Windows: Depending on the used file system, `FindFirstFileName` and `FindNextFileName`
could be useful, but as said, they won´t always work (ReFS...)

Comment: On Windows, a symlink is implemented by a reparse point, which can be detected by `GetFileAttributes()` and `FindFirstFile()`/`FindNextFile()` via the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT` attribute. Hard links must also be detectable as well (I'm not sure how) because the command-line `fsutil` tool has a [`hardlink list`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788097.aspx) parameter that can find hard links to a given file (at least on Win7/2008+) and SysInternals also has a [`FindLinks`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/hh290814) tool for finding hard links.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I forgot `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT` (facepalm) . But still, it´s not that easy to check if it is a symlink or another kind of RP. And yes, hard links are detectable like described in the answer, but only on certain file systems (NTFS yes, ReFS not in all versions...)

Comment: Actually, when the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT` attribute is present on a file/folder, the `WIN32_FIND_DATA` struct from `FindFirstFile()`/`FindNextFile()` specifies the [Reparse Point Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365511.aspx) in the `dwReserved0` field. One of the available tags is `IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK`. This is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363940.aspx): "*you can determine if a reparse point is a symbolic link by testing whether the tag value is IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK*."

Comment: FindFirstFileNameW/FindNextFileNameW should work on all standard, local file systems that have support for hard links.  That's probably all you need so far as hard links go.